Razorpay Payment Failure Redirection Prevents User Interaction with Button in React
I'm integrating Razorpay into my React project for handling payments. The payment flow works, but I'm facing an issue when a payment fails. Specifically, after a payment failure, the page redirects to the failure page, but I cannot interact with a button on that page. In the browser's network tab, I can see that the request returns a status 200 for the initiator @trycatch.ts:180, but the button remains unclickable.
Code:
const App = () => {
  const loadScript = (src) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = src;
      script.onload = () => {
        resolve(true);
      };
      script.onerror = () => {
        resolve(false);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js");
  }, []);

  const handlePayment = async () => {
    if (!loadingCourseInformation && courseInfo && !loadingCreateOrder) {
      try {
        setProcessingPayment(true);
        const amount = appliedDiscount ? appliedDiscount : courseInfo.price;
        const payload = {
          amount: amount.toString(),
          currency: "INR",
          course_id: courseInfo.course_id.toString(),
        };

        await createOrderPayload(payload);
      } catch (err) {
        setProcessingPayment(false);
        if (err.response) {
          notifyUser(
            "Order Error",
            "An error occurred while creating the order.",
            "error"
          );
        } else if (err.request) {
          notifyUser(
            "Network Error",
            "Network error, please try again.",
            "warning"
          );
        } else {
          notifyUser(
            "Unexpected Error",
            `Unexpected error: ${err.message}`,
            "error"
          );
        }
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (createOrderData) {
      setProcessingPayment(true);
      const amount = appliedDiscount ? appliedDiscount : courseInfo.price;
      const options = {
        key: userData.REACT_APP_RAYZOR_KEY,
        amount: amount * 100,
        currency: "INR",
        name: "MIT",
        description: courseInfo.course_name,
        image: mtsLogo,
        order_id: createOrderData.orderId,
        handler: async (response) => {
          const verifyPayload = {
            razorpay_order_id: response.razorpay_order_id,
            razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
            razorpay_signature: response.razorpay_signature,
          };
          try {
            await verifyOrderPayload(verifyPayload);
            razorpay.close();
          } catch (verificationError) {
            console.log(verificationError);
          }
        },
      };

      const razorpay = new window.Razorpay(options);

      razorpay.open();
      razorpay.on("payment.failed", function (response) {
        razorpay.close();
        setProcessingPayment(false);
        console.error("Payment failed:", response.error);
        navigate(`/app/payment/failure/${createOrderData.payment.payment_id}`);
      });
    }
  }, [createOrderData]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={handlePayment}
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        className="course-price-wrapper__button-wrapper--buy-now"
      >
        Buy Now
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

